# Laravel form getting non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I have some problems with Laravel form. I have one form that needs to be validated and in form is only data that needs to be changed. But problem is I have some data like this in code:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <span>{{$trip->country->name}}</span>
</div>
```

And when I click on save button it's giving error, but changes is still updated.

> Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   /mnt/c/Projects/b4g/resources/views/frontend/planner/file.blade.php)

And as non-object is giving {`{$trip->country->name}}` but actually that's should not be updated!

I will post form here:
Sorry I have to upload PHP form in pastebin.com/93kkUg4X

```
<form id="group-details-update" action="{{action('PlannerController@updateDetails', ['id' => $trip->id])}}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <div class="row form-group {{$errors->has && $errors->has('name') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label class="pull-right">{{untrans('labels.organisation_guest')}}:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <span class="text-readonly {{$errors->any()?'hidden':''}}">{{$trip->company->name}}</span>
                <input class="form-control {{$errors->any()?'':'hidden'}}" name="name" type="text" data-value="{{$trip->company->name}}" value="{{$trip->company->name}}">
                @if($errors && $errors->has('name'))
                <span class="help-block"><small>{{$errors->first('name')}}</small></span>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group {{$errors && $errors->has('division') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label class="pull-right">{{untrans('labels.division')}}:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <span class="text-readonly {{$errors->any()?'hidden':''}}">{{$trip->company->division}}</span>
                <input class="form-control {{$errors->any()?'':'hidden'}}" name="division" type="text" data-value="{{$trip->company->division}}" value="{{$trip->company->division}}">
                @if($errors && $errors->has('division'))
                <span class="help-block"><small>{{$errors->first('division')}}</small></span>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group {{$errors && $errors->has('street') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label class="pull-right">{{utrans('labels.street_address')}}:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <span class="text-readonly {{$errors->any()?'hidden':''}}">{{$trip->company->street}}</span>
                <input class="form-control {{$errors->any()?'':'hidden'}}" name="street" type="text" data-value="{{$trip->company->street}}" value="{{$trip->company->street}}">
                @if($errors && $errors->has('street'))
                <span class="help-block"><small>{{$errors->first('street')}}</small></span>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group {{$errors && $errors->has('zip') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label class="pull-right">{{utrans('labels.zip_code')}}:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <span class="text-readonly {{$errors->any()?'hidden':''}}">{{$trip->company->zip}}</span>
                <input class="form-control {{$errors->any()?'':'hidden'}}" name="zip" type="text" data-value="{{$trip->company->zip}}" value="{{$trip->company->zip}}">
                @if($errors && $errors->has('zip'))
                <span class="help-block"><small>{{$errors->first('zip')}}</small></span>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-group {{$errors && $errors->has('city') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label class="pull-right">{{utrans('labels.city')}}:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <span class="text-readonly {{$errors->any()?'hidden':''}}">{{$trip->company->city}}</span>
                <input class="form-control {{$errors->any()?'':'hidden'}}" name="city" type="text" data-value="{{$trip->company->city}}" value="{{$trip->company->city}}">
                @if($errors && $errors->has('city'))
                <span class="help-block"><small>{{$errors->first('city')}}</small></span>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4">
                <button class="btn btn-primary edit {{$errors->any()?'hidden':''}}" type="button">{{untrans('labels.edit_guest_data')}}</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary save {{$errors->any()?'':'hidden'}}" type="submit">{{utrans('labels.save')}}</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary abort {{$errors->any()?'':'hidden'}}" type="button">{{utrans('labels.abort')}}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form i see

```
<span class="text-readonly {{$errors->any()?'hidden':''}}">{{$trip->company->name}}</span>
```

but you ask about

```
$trip->country->name
```

form updates `company` object but not `country`

Comment: Yes that is problem this $trip->country->name is in span class but not in form, it's still get's this variable to be changed. I don't know why.